# How can I make a button resize responsively to the window size?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I've made this very simple form with an image as the button.

Is there a way to make the button resize responsively to the window size, in a similar manner to input - i.e. the button becomes progressively smaller as the window does?

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin-left: 25%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.form-control {
  position: relative;
  top: 65px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 35vw;
  height: 1.8vw;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 40vw;
  border: 0;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/9n3Zvcr.png) no-repeat;
  width: 210px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<form action="send_form_email.php" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="EmailTestForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="button"></button>
</form>
</body>
```

I've tried setting the button width to a percentage and using max-width, to no avail. I'm not sure if media query can be used to rescale the button smoothly.

I started learning html three days ago so I really don't have a clue what I'm doing.

Comment: At this point maybe you can be interested in learn "responsive" frameworks like bootstrap. Just a suggestion.

Comment: What is `left: 40vw;`?  You probably want to do some research on [responsive design using CSS](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/) and media queries.  Also, I would suggest that you use actual HTML layout for positioning things, NOT relative positioning.

Comment: Why is this with the `jquery` tag? There is no Javascript code **at all**!

Answer (score 0):

Try using percentages rather than pixels.

So, if you want to make it responsive, do something like this:

```
width:5%; //Will take 5% of the page
width:50%; //Will take half of the page
```

Using percentages could be hard, but it is the easiest way to make button sized responsive.

To learn more about CSS, Javascript, HTML5, PHP, and more, go to: http://www.w3schools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that could be a good starting point for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bz60swhf/.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    <button type="submit">
        <img src = "http://i.imgur.com/9n3Zvcr.png" />
    </button>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

form {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

form > input[type = "email"] {
    outline: 1px solid gray;
    font: normal 20px/2 Sans-Serif;
    width: 70%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
    max-width: 30%;
    height: 40px;
    background: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

button > img {
    height: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 394px) {
    button > img {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
}
```